# Snake Game Java Gui

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener, keylistener

Hello I've started to develop a snake game recently. I'm in the beginning stage where I have a moving object and a dot for it to eat but my main issues are how can I check if the snake "ate" the dot,and how can I make it disappear?
Any help would be very appreciated.

here is the following code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;    
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;    
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;    
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;    
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.*;    
import java.util.Random;    
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gui extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener{

    Random rnd= new Random();

 int pointx=100 + (int)(Math.random() * ((400- 100) + 1));;

 int pointy=100 + (int)(Math.random() * ((300 - 100) + 1));

 private String text;

    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);

    int x = 300, y = 178, velx = 0, vely = 0;


      public Gui() 
      {
          tm.start();

          addKeyListener(this);

          setFocusable(true);

      }
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 35, 15);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(pointx,pointy, 20,20);

        }

      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
      {
          int c = e.getKeyCode();
          if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
          {
              velx = -1;
              vely = 0;
          }
          if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
          {
              velx = 0;
              vely = -1;
          }
          if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
          {
              velx = 1;
              vely = 0;
          }
          if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
          {
              velx = 0;
              vely = 1;
          }
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          x += velx;
          y += vely;
          repaint();
          borders(e);

      }
      public void borders(ActionEvent e) {
          if (x < 0) {
              velx = 0;
              x = 0;
              JOptionPane
                      .showMessageDialog(null, "you hit the borders you lost!");
              System.exit(0);
          }
          if (x > 530) {
              velx = 0;
              x = 530;
              JOptionPane
                      .showMessageDialog(null, "you hit the borders you lost!");
              System.exit(0);
          }
          if (y < 0) {
              velx = 0;
              y = 0;
              JOptionPane
                      .showMessageDialog(null, "you hit the borders you lost!");
              System.exit(0);
          }
          if (y > 330) {
              velx = 0;
              y = 330;
              JOptionPane
                      .showMessageDialog(null, "you hit the borders you lost!");
              System.exit(0);

          }
      }
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("gui");
          frame.add(new Gui());
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setSize(600, 400);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      }
```

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the "head" of the snake and the "target".  If the head and target are at the same point, then it ate it, once eaten, you would either reset the "treat" to a new location or set it to `null` and allow the next paint cycle to update the graphics. You will need to use a similar technique for detecting if the snake ran into itself.

Comment: I read very quickly, it seems you read the x and y of the snake, why you not compare them with the x and y of the point? if they are the same you know that the snake is passing over the point.

By the way, your code is a bit confuse, I can't see where you use the pointx and pointy to create the point...

I think you should stop a moment and re-think about the structure of the project.

You can create a class "Point" that represent the "food" for the snake.
Then you need a class Snake, formed by many Points, and a method to move it (take the last point and put it after the first)
and so on..

Answer (score 5):

First things first: Your GUI should be seperate from your game logic.

Basically, you want one or more classes to encapsulate game state. This GameState class has a function which returns a list of circles to draw, and another function to accept input. The GUI class handles setting up the panels and performing the draw requests. Then things become really simple. To make a dot disappear, simply remove it from the list. To check if two things collided, compare their positions.

I actually made a Snake game in Java a while back myself. Here's the list of classes I had. Keep in mind this is just a suggestion: you'll need more or less classes depending on personal preference and the complexity of the game.

- GameInstance - holds the game logic
- GameWindow - the gui portion
- MainLoop - sets up the event loop
- Snake - holds information about
  the    snake
- Pnt2 - a 2d point, with logic for addition,
  subtraction,    distance tests, etc

Obviously, this is just one way to do things, but it is the approach that I'd recommend.

Comment: thank you very much but in my game my snake is actually a rectangle that is filled to the frame and so is my dot so the issue is how to make it disappear.i thought that if the snake would touch the dot i would color it white but its not very effictive, how can you remove a rectangle from a jframe in a clean way?

Comment: I just cleared the entire frame and redrew everything each tick. It's a lot easier than trying to manually find the difference from the previous frame and only drawing the changed parts.

Comment: nice,il try my best to make it work. and again thank you